# Resize iframe height according to content height in it

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, iframe

I am opening my blog page in my website. The problem is I can give a width to an iframe but the height should be dynamic so that there is no scrollbar in the iframe, and it looks like a single page...

I have tried various JavaScript code to calculate the height of the content but all of them give an *access denied permission* error and is of no use.

```
<iframe src="http://bagtheplanet.blogspot.com/" name="ifrm" id="ifrm" width="1024px" ></iframe>
```

Can we use Ajax to calculate height or maybe using PHP?

Answer (score 60):

To directly answer your two subquestions: No, you cannot do this with Ajax, nor can you calculate it with PHP.

What I have done in the past is use a trigger from the iframe'd page in `window.onload` (NOT `domready`, as it can take a while for images to load) to pass the page's body height to the parent.

```
<body onload='parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight)'>
```

Then the `parent.resizeIframe` looks like this:

```
function resizeIframe(newHeight)
{
    document.getElementById('blogIframe').style.height = parseInt(newHeight,10) + 10 + 'px';
}
```

Et voila, you have a robust resizer that triggers once the page is fully rendered with no nasty `contentdocument` vs `contentWindow` fiddling :)

Sure, now people will see your iframe at default height first, but this can be easily handled by hiding your iframe at first and just showing a 'loading' image. Then, when the `resizeIframe` function kicks in, put two extra lines in there that will hide the loading image, and show the iframe for that faux Ajax look.

Of course, this only works from the same domain, so you may want to have a proxy PHP script to embed this stuff, and once you go there, you might as well just embed your blog's RSS feed directly into your site with PHP.

Comment: I'm using iframe to load pages. My iframe is in the main page which does not re-load once loaded. Only the pages in iframe changes based on the link clicked from main page that target the iframe. How do I adjust height of iframe in this case.

Comment: I added this to the bottom of my iframe page... the load time was causing a fake px height when it was nestled in the body onload event. <script>
parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight);
</script>

Comment: @SchizoDuckie very nice answer short and simple

Comment: @SchizoDuckie i face one problem iframe and body size is only increases not decreases any solution ??

Comment: I'm finding this isn't resizing the first time I load the parent screen. The child takes a bit of time to load.   I'm also seeing the same lack of decrease.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome, but seems to not work in IE10. Still using it. Who uses IE anyways? :)

Comment: @The Muffin Man, A lot of businesses stll use IE11 as their standard browser.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('foo').height = document.getElementById('foo').contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
```

Comment: The script confuses me. I like to practise with a real site: mathsearchun.blogspot.com/. Is the "id" the innermost div "HTML3" or the outermost div "outer-wrapper"? I got errors such as "contentWindow is undefined" and "document.getElementById("id") is null", in Firebug. What do they mean?

Comment: The element you want to get is the iframe, amazon in your case I guess. 

"contentWindow is undefined" probably means that the element you grabbed doesn't have that property/element.

You need to use document.getElementById("amazon") to get your iframe.

Comment: This works in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox, can you improve on this to include Firefox?

Answer (score 4):

Fitting IFRAME contents is kind of an easy thing to [find on Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=fit+iframe+to+contents). Here's [one solution](http://www.kaali.co.uk/article-Cross-bowser-iframe-auto-resize-script-94.htm):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function autoIframe(frameId) {
       try {
          frame = document.getElementById(frameId);
          innerDoc = (frame.contentDocument) ? frame.contentDocument : frame.contentWindow.document;
          objToResize = (frame.style) ? frame.style : frame;
          objToResize.height = innerDoc.body.scrollHeight + 10;
       }
       catch(err) {
          window.status = err.message;
       }
    }
</script>
```

This of course doesn't solve the cross-domain problem you are having... Setting `document.domain` might help if these sites are in the same place. I don't think there is a solution if you are iframe-ing random sites.

Comment: You're missing a unit on the height assignment, ie 'px'. Doesn't this cause a failure in standards mode?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my solution to the problem using MooTools which works in Firefox 3.6, Safari 4.0.4 and Internet Explorer 7:

```
var iframe_container = $('iframe_container_id');
var iframe_style = {
    height: 300,
    width: '100%'
};
if (!Browser.Engine.trident) {
    // IE has hasLayout issues if iframe display is none, so don't use the loading class
    iframe_container.addClass('loading');
    iframe_style.display = 'none';
}
this.iframe = new IFrame({
    frameBorder: 0,
    src: "http://www.youriframeurl.com/",
    styles: iframe_style,
    events: {
        'load': function() {
            var innerDoc = (this.contentDocument) ? this.contentDocument : this.contentWindow.document;
            var h = this.measure(function(){
                return innerDoc.body.scrollHeight;
            });            
            this.setStyles({
                height: h.toInt(),
                display: 'block'
            });
            if (!Browser.Engine.trident) {
                iframe_container.removeClass('loading');
            }
        }
    }
}).inject(iframe_container);
```

Style the "loading" class to show an Ajax loading graphic in the middle of the iframe container. Then for browsers other than Internet Explorer, it will display the full height IFRAME once the loading of its content is complete and remove the loading graphic.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my `onload` event handler.

I use an IFRAME within a [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) dialog. Different usages will need some adjustments.
This seems to do the trick for me (for now) in Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 3.5.
It might need some extra tweaking, but the general idea should be clear.

```
    function onLoadDialog(frame) {
    try {
        var body = frame.contentDocument.body;
        var $body = $(body);
        var $frame = $(frame);
        var contentDiv = frame.parentNode;
        var $contentDiv = $(contentDiv);

        var savedShow = $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'show');
        var position = $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'position');
        // disable show effect to enable re-positioning (UI bug?)
        $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'show', null);
        // show dialog, otherwise sizing won't work
        $contentDiv.dialog('open');

        // Maximize frame width in order to determine minimal scrollHeight
        $frame.css('width', $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'maxWidth') -
                contentDiv.offsetWidth + frame.offsetWidth);

        var minScrollHeight = body.scrollHeight;
        var maxWidth = body.offsetWidth;
        var minWidth = 0;
        // decrease frame width until scrollHeight starts to grow (wrapping)
        while (Math.abs(maxWidth - minWidth) > 10) {
            var width = minWidth + Math.ceil((maxWidth - minWidth) / 2);
            $body.css('width', width);
            if (body.scrollHeight > minScrollHeight) {
                minWidth = width;
            } else {
                maxWidth = width;
            }
        }
        $frame.css('width', maxWidth);
        // use maximum height to avoid vertical scrollbar (if possible)
        var maxHeight = $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'maxHeight')
        $frame.css('height', maxHeight);
        $body.css('width', '');
        // correct for vertical scrollbar (if necessary)
        while (body.clientWidth < maxWidth) {
            $frame.css('width', maxWidth + (maxWidth - body.clientWidth));
        }

        var minScrollWidth = body.scrollWidth;
        var minHeight = Math.min(minScrollHeight, maxHeight);
        // descrease frame height until scrollWidth decreases (wrapping)
        while (Math.abs(maxHeight - minHeight) > 10) {
            var height = minHeight + Math.ceil((maxHeight - minHeight) / 2);
            $body.css('height', height);
            if (body.scrollWidth < minScrollWidth) {
                minHeight = height;
            } else {
                maxHeight = height;
            }
        }
        $frame.css('height', maxHeight);
        $body.css('height', '');

        // reset widths to 'auto' where possible
        $contentDiv.css('width', 'auto');
        $contentDiv.css('height', 'auto');
        $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'width', 'auto');

        // re-position the dialog
        $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'position', position);

        // hide dialog
        $contentDiv.dialog('close');
        // restore show effect
        $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'show', savedShow);
        // open using show effect
        $contentDiv.dialog('open');
        // remove show effect for consecutive requests
        $contentDiv.dialog('option', 'show', null);

        return;
    }

    //An error is raised if the IFrame domain != its container's domain
    catch (e) {
        window.status = 'Error: ' + e.number + '; ' + e.description;
        alert('Error: ' + e.number + '; ' + e.description);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to acquire all the necessary iframe events from an external script. For instance, you have a script which creates the iFrame using document.createElement; in this same script you temporarily have access to the contents of the iFrame.

```
var dFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
dFrame.src = "http://www.example.com";
// Acquire onload and resize the iframe
dFrame.onload = function()
{
    // Setting the content window's resize function tells us when we've changed the height of the internal document
    // It also only needs to do what onload does, so just have it call onload
    dFrame.contentWindow.onresize = function() { dFrame.onload() };
    dFrame.style.height = dFrame.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
window.onresize = function() {
    dFrame.onload();
}
```

This works because dFrame stays in scope in those functions, giving you access to the external iFrame element from within the scope of the frame, allowing you to see the actual document height and expand it as necessary. This example will work in firefox but nowhere else; I could give you the workarounds, but you can figure out the rest ;)

Comment: Trigger happy on the response. Scott above uses a similar script, but the inclusion of contentWindow.onresize allows you to resize the iframe if its contents change. It's also useful for fluid width iframes.

Comment: What does `fobj` in this script refer to?

Comment: I think it was a transcription error. I copied some code and forgot to swap fobj in one context; it should be dFrame. Fixed in answer.

Answer (score 0):

@SchizoDuckie's answer is very elegant and lightweight, but due to Webkit's lack of implementation for scrollHeight (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollHeight)), does not work on Webkit-based browsers (Safari, Chrome, various and sundry mobile platforms).

For this basic idea to work on Webkit along with Gecko and Trident browsers, one need only replace

```
<body onload='parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight)'>
```

with

```
<body onload='parent.resizeIframe(document.body.offsetHeight)'>
```

So long as everything is on the same domain, this works quite well.

Comment: According to http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html and a quick test, scrollHeight works on Safari and Chrome (OS X). OffsetHeight did not work correctly in both browsers in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you can change for even when you want. this example use jQuery.

```
$('#iframe').live('mousemove', function (event) {   
    var theFrame = $(this, parent.document.body);
    this.height($(document.body).height() - 350);           
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spent the better part of 3 days wrestling with this. I'm working on an application that loads other applications into itself while maintaining a fixed header and a fixed footer. Here's what I've come up with. (I also used EasyXDM, with success, but pulled it out later to use this solution.)

Make sure to run this code AFTER the `<iframe>` exists in the DOM. Put it into the page that pulls in the iframe (the parent).

```
// get the iframe
var theFrame = $("#myIframe");
// set its height to the height of the window minus the combined height of fixed header and footer
theFrame.height(Number($(window).height()) - 80);

function resizeIframe() {
    theFrame.height(Number($(window).height()) - 80);
}

// setup a resize method to fire off resizeIframe.
// use timeout to filter out unnecessary firing.
var TO = false;
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (TO !== false) clearTimeout(TO);
    TO = setTimeout(resizeIframe, 500); //500 is time in miliseconds
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using `scrolling=no` attribute on the iframe tag. Mozilla also has an `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` CSS property you may look into.

In terms of the height, you could also try `height=100%` on the iframe tag.