# CSS: Make iframe full with and height, no scrollbars

Tags: css

How can I have full height on my iframe, so I dont have a scrollbar if it exceeds the specified `height: 500px;` - I want to only have the page scrollbar existing and not the iframe scrollbar.

I know you can hide the scrollbar, but then you cannot see all the content in the iframe.

How can you do this?

width: 100% works perfectly, but height: 100% wont.

Check http://jsfiddle.net/5PKqf/

If it worked it should have shown the whole website in the iframe

Comment: Rather than what you are stating, it would be far easier to disable the main page's scrollbars than the iframe's - you can then rely on the user using the iframe scrollbars as if they were the main page ones. You can do this with `overflow:hidden` on your `html` and `body` elements oh and make sure you reset margin and padding for both those elements too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize iframe height according to content height in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525992/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height-in-it)

Answer (score 1):

give html a height: 100%

```
html{ height: 100%; }
```

Comment: +1 but you'll need all parents to the target element to have height 100%, so in this case `body` as well as `html`.

Comment: Hmm but check this: http://jsfiddle.net/5PKqf/3/ There's two scrollbars, thats not what i wish, i wish only 1 scrollbar where the page gets bigger depending on the iframe page

Comment: oke go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525992/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height-in-it