# Display cross domain page inside div, iframe, frame with original height?

Tags: php, css, iframe, cross-domain

I have created a page in which I am showing *A websites Page* (situated some where on web );

I used *iframe* but puzzled with the height issues I solved width issues for 950px only with `css3` but my need is **full height as target website** but that is not working with *cross domain pages* (I've done with same domain successfully).

Now I want to do it either with `PHP` using `get_file_content()` or some other putting it into div , `iframe` or in `frames` whatever works (**and also pages must be accessible as it is from main sites**)

The container will change its content with hyper link click.

Please help me to resolve the issues.
I've tried many more methods including **jquery**, **js**, **php**, **css**  and blah blah blah with no success.

before commenting or answering please visit [THIS LINK](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Hanukkah&view=detail&id=4C72782A5D36074B1DA0CAEEC89F84A9EDD30C35&first=1)

**I need some thing like** [this](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=Hanukkah&view=detail&id=4C72782A5D36074B1DA0CAEEC89F84A9EDD30C35&first=1)

**Please check this and alter here**
[To See My page Click here](http://communique-isite.com/ipg/default1.htm)

**Note:**

1. I have no access of target site so I can't put attributes on target
   page and get back to iframe page.
2. I have 100+ pages to show so no
   specific method can be used i need any generalized technology.
3. One more thing i don't want scrolling in my page.

**Efforts done :**

[Ajax/Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963799/ajax-jquery-load-webpage-content-into-a-div-on-page-load)

[PHP Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525992/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height-in-it)

Comment: You need to watch this talk on seamless iframes: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQCm8VYn93Y it explains a lot of workaround to get content in iframes to play nice with the parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "iframe'd" html, have:

```
<body onload="parent.resize_iframe(document.body.scrollHeight)">
```

and in the page that iframes:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function resize_iframe(new_height) {
        document.getElementById('iframed').style.height =   parseInt(new_height, 10) + 60 + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

I used 60px to fix potential padding etc.

Note that they have to be under the same domain for this to work, otherwise you might have to run:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.domain =   "domain.com";
</script>
```

On either or both. This is required so that the browser may interact between them.

Comment: i think that it wont work with cross browser domains have you checked it

Comment: Added a text for that aswell.

Comment: one thing what i wrote in my question that i don't have access to targeted page and i can either add or alter the page content.

Comment: Maybe you can change your own page to the domain of the iframe'd one?

Comment: I am still unable to do this please give an example

Comment: Erhm seems like there's not much more to do, other than running a cURL, read of relevant page and output in on your own. Then makes all css and js link accordingly.

Comment: any help regarding this if yes please share links

Comment: [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) is used by php to read of the content of other webpages, and can return it as a string. This string can be echo'd on own page. Only consider that all relative paths, suchs as `href="/home"` will need to be fixed.

Comment: document.domain =   "domain.com"; is not working giving error

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
<frameset rows="*">
    <frame frameborder=0 src="http://www.discountautoparts.com/" scrolling="auto" noresize>
</frameset>
```

If you do that it should look like this [picture](http://f.cl.ly/items/2h2e13150u1K373n1E2Z/Screen%20shot%202012-12-11%20at%207.47.53%20AM.png)

Comment: it even not doing any thing, page is blank