# Changing IFRAME height dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How is it possible to fix the height issue of Google Trend charts dynamically.
For an example take a look on the output of following code.

```
<iframe width="600" height="320" src="http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=css-showcase&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=600&h=320" style="border: none;"></iframe>

<hr>
first contents

<hr>

<iframe width="600" height="320" src="http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?hl=en-US&q=html5&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=600&h=320" style="border: none;"></iframe>

<hr>
second contents
```

on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yzw8Y/

Comment: *For an example take a look on the output of following code.* Why don't you build it on jsFiddle so that we can do just that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize iframe height according to content height in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/525992/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height-in-it)

Answer (score 1):

i didn't test it, but this could work.

```
function autoResize(id)
{
   var newheight;
   newheight=document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
   document.getElementById(id).height=newheight + "px";
}

<iframe id="frame1" onload="autoResize('frame1')" ... >
```

Comment: I removed `height="320"` and `&h=320` from iframe source and this work perfectly.

Comment: I am really sorry for my previous comment. I tried it on both IFRAME but it is not working. [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zvuLM/)

Answer (score -2):

set id for iframe

and in jquery set height

$('#idval').css('height','800px');

Comment: This is equivalent to `width="800"`. I need to dynamically set height of an IFRAME based on it's inner contents.

Comment: For that you set a max-width. No need to set width. Based on content width will  extend up to max-width

Comment: sorry I meant to say `height="800"`

Comment: set max-height=800px and height=100px;