# iFrame postMessage Once Modal Loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've got a parent page that loads an iFrame within a modal. I want the iFrame and containing modal to resize dynamically based on the content height.

While I can send the height from the child page to the parent using postMessage when the parent page loads, the height is always wrong because the modal isn't visible yet.

How can I send the height once the modal has actually changed from display:none to display:block?

Here's what I'm doing now:

**Parent Page**

```
function receiveMessage(e) {
    // Check to make sure that this message came from the correct domain.
    if (e.origin !== "http://www.example.com")
        return;

    // Update the div element to display the message.
    alert("Message Received: " + e.data);
    var pixels = e.data;
    pixels +=32;
    console.log(pixels);
    $('#modal').css('height', pixels+'px');
    $('#iframe').css('height', pixels+'px');

}
```

**Child Page**

```
  function sendHeight () {
    var containerHeight = $('#main_container').height();
    alert("Height " + containerHeight);
    parent.postMessage(containerHeight, 'http://www.example.com');
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use an interval function to check when the modal is actually visible and then apply all the changes:

```
var timer;
timer = setInterval( checkelemnt, 300 );
function checkelemnt(){

    //is the modal visible yet?

    if(! $("#modal':visible").length)
    {
        //wait
    }else{
        //resize the modal
        //and clear the interval

        clearInterval( timer );
    }

}
```

Another neat solution is using the [**easyXDM**](http://easyxdm.net/wp/) , especially if you are trying to make a Cross Domain call to the iframe

Answer (score 6):

## EDIT 2:

This isn't meant to answer the issue of Chrome/Firefox/etc onload differences (chrome onload fires before images are loaded giving the smaller frame height) but if you were already getting around that with your own code you can do this to display the modal with the proper height.

### JS

```
// edited old function
function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin !== "http://example.com") return;
  $('#modal').css('height', parseInt(event.data, 10) + 10 + 'px');
  $('#iframe').css('height', parseInt(event.data, 10) + 'px');
}
// new code
$('#show').click(function(e) {
  // use if CSS hides modal initially
  $('#modal').css('display', 'block');
  // use if hidden with inline style
  $('#modal').show();
  $('#iframe').attr('src', $('#iframe').data('src'));
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="modal" style="display: none;"><!-- for inline styling -->
  <iframe data-src="http://example.com" src="" id="iframe">
  </iframe>
</div>
<button id="show">Open the modal</button>
```

GLHF

## EDIT:

*(I deleted the original part of the answer now that I know your requirements)*
**[Still got the inspiration from here though.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525992/resize-iframe-height-according-to-content-height-in-it)**

### Take #2:

I happen to run the same server under multiple domains and I finally have a use for it (*yay*).

So the **parent page** is on a different domain than the **child page**.

The **parent page** is only allowed this re-sizing ***`madness`*** if it's own origin matches what the child passes as an argument in `postMessage();` - *thus eliminating those darn leachers who want to re-size like us big kids.*

The **child page** is only allowed to be re-sized if it comes from a hood near you (specified in `receiveMessage()` as a conditional) - also known as matching the origin

This is what you already knew but since I'm slow (and surely other Googlers in the future will be as well), I'm spelling it out here for *us*.

**Here's my corrected code:**

### Parent:

```
var addEvent = function (element, myEvent, fnc) {
    return ((element.attachEvent) ? element.attachEvent('on' + myEvent, fnc) : element.addEventListener(myEvent, fnc, false));
};
addEvent(window, "message", receiveMessage);
function receiveMessage(event) {
  if (event.origin !== "http://www.myChildPageInsideMe.com") return;
  $('#iframe').css('height', parseInt(event.data, 10) + 10 + 'px');
}
```

### Child / iFrizzame:

```
<body onload="parent.postMessage(document.body.scrollHeight, 'http://www.theOverBearingMotherPage.com');">
```

Feel free to use whatever event handling code you like.  *I like mine :)*

And of course...

## [see it in action here (page on different domain than iFrame)](http://www.fleeceitout.com/event.html)

---

Comment: This doesn't actually work because of the modal issue, nor does it solve the cross-domain problem.

Comment: you didn't say anything about a cross domain problem in your question.  when you load the page does devtools give you cross domain error

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. Figured the fact that I was using postMessage made it obvious that I needed a cross-domain approach. No, I'm not getting a cross-domain error using my approach, but I do get it with yours, obviously.

Comment: OK gotcha.  I'd like to say "fixed now" but I'll let you be the judge.  See above edits.

Comment: So, you're still not addressing the modal issue, and at least in Chrome the iFrame is smaller than the height of the iFrame's content.

Comment: Addressed now but it's not clear if you need the iframe loading immediately or not.  The new code loads the iframe upon modal opening then dynamically changes both heights.  Same link for preview as last one.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you control the content in the parent and child frames. Excellent.

I would recommend:

1. using `postMessage()` to send a message from the child to the parent once the child is able to process messages
2. then send a message from the parent to the child once the parent displays the child and the child is visible
3. the child then sends the message to the parent regarding its content dimensions
4. the parent then resizes the iframe and the modal per the desired dimensions

The downside is there's likely to be a little flickering. You might be able give the modal a large negative `left` CSS property or something similar to render out of the user's sight.

Security note: be sure to check the `origin` and/or `source` properties of the message event to make sure you have received a message from a trusted / expected source.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in my program. Hope it helps you out

**Parent Page**

```
function dyniframesize(frameId) {
        var pTar = null;
        if (document.getElementById) {
            pTar = document.getElementById(frameId);
        } else {
            eval('pTar = ' + frameId + ';');
        }
        if (pTar && !window.opera) {
            // begin resizing iframe
            pTar.style.display = "block";
            pTar.height = "10px";   // 
            if (pTar.contentDocument && pTar.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight) {
                pTar.height = pTar.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight;
                pTar.width = pTar.contentDocument.body.scrollWidth;
            } else if (pTar.Document && pTar.Document.body.scrollHeight) {
                // ie5+
                pTar.height = pTar.Document.body.scrollHeight;
                pTar.width = pTar.Document.body.scrollWidth;
            }
        }
    }

<iframe id="frm" name="frm" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" onload="javascript:dyniframesize('frm');" width="100%" src=""></iframe>
```